¿Cómo transformar las tuplas en numeros enteros o sectores en python?
Hice el siguiente código en Python:
def busqueda_secuencialR(AE,dato,NRO_columna):
    cant_datos_est = 6
    arreglo_est = [[0]*cant_datos_est for n in range(8)]
    AE = arreglo_est
    pos = 0
    while dato != AE[pos,NRO_columna] and pos < 8:
        pos = pos + 1
        if pos == -1:
            AE[pos,1] = username_r
            password_r = getpass.getpass(" | -----  Ingresa tu contraseña  ----- |\n ")
            AE[pos,2] = password_r
            fecha_nac_r = input(" | ----- Ingrese su fecha de nacimiento ----- |\n ")
            AE[pos,3] = fecha_nac_r
            biografía_r = input(" | ----- Ingrese su biografía ----- |\n ")
            AE[pos,4] = biografía_r
            hobbies_r = input(" | ----- Ingrese sus hobbies ----- |\n ")
            AE[pos,5] = hobbies_r
            AE[pos,6] = "activo"

Pero me salta error en la parte del while dato != AE[pos,NRO_columna] and pos < 8: ; diciendo que los índices de las listas deben ser números enteros o sectores, no tuplas.
¿Cómo podría solucionarlo?

En vez de AE[pos,NRO_columna], ¿querrías decir AE[pos][NRO_columna]?

AE (y arreglo_est, son el mismo objeto, AE = arreglo_est no crea ninguna copia...) es una lista de listas, no un array 2D de NumPy (para los cuales si es correcta esa sintaxis). Debes indizar como comenta aeportugal. El error hace mención a una tupla porque AE[pos,NRO_columna] es en realidad azúcar sintáctico para AE[(pos, NRO_columna)] y los indices tiene que ser enteros o slices (rebanados).

Ten en cuenta que [0]*cant_datos_est crea copias de una lista de un único elemento. Esto puede dar lugar a comportamientos inesperados. Quizás prefieras hacer [0 for _ in range(cant_datos_est)]. Aunque mi recomendación es que crees una clase para guardar tus datos.
